# Bicep: Creating multiple topics with multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I'm new to bicep and have been struggling to implement a Bicep script to deploy an Azure Service bus with many topics and subscriptions.

Each topic I add has a variable number of subscriptions (for example the notifications topic might have 3 subscriptions, but the analysis topic might have 2).

Is there a way I can loop through and create all of the topic resources and then loop through all of the subscriptions and add them to the correct topic definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kinda depends on how many topics we're talking about here.
If you're just creating a small number then i'd do something like this;

##### TopicsAndSubs.bicep

```
@description('Name of the Service Bus namespace')
param serviceBusNamespaceName string

@description('Name of the Topic')
param serviceBusTopicName string = 'theweather'

param topicSubscriptions int = 3

resource serviceBusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-10-01-preview' existing = {
  name: serviceBusNamespaceName
}

resource serviceBusTopic 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-10-01-preview' = {
  parent: serviceBusNamespace
  name: serviceBusTopicName
  properties: {

  }

  resource sub 'subscriptions' = [for i in range(0,topicSubscriptions): {
    name: 'sub-${i}'
    properties: {}
  }]
}
```

---

However if it's going to be even more wacky, then you'll need to use **modules** (a separate file for topics and one for the subscriptions). Something like this;

##### Topics.bicep

```
@description('Name of the Service Bus namespace')
param serviceBusNamespaceName string

@description('Name of the Topic')
param topicsAndSubscriptions array = [
  {
    name: 'notification'
    subscriptions: [
      'none'
      'ntwo'
      'nthree'
      'nfour'
    ]
  }
  {
    name: 'analysis'
    subscriptions: [
      'aone'
      'atwo'
      'athree'
      'afour'
    ]
  }
]

resource serviceBusNamespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-10-01-preview' existing = {
  name: serviceBusNamespaceName
}

resource serviceBusTopic 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-10-01-preview' = [ for topic in topicsAndSubscriptions: {
  parent: serviceBusNamespace
  name: topic.name
  properties: {

  }
}]

module subs 'sub.bicep' = [ for topic in topicsAndSubscriptions: {
  name: '${topic.name}-subs'
  params: {
    servicebusNamespaceName: serviceBusNamespaceName
    topicName: topic.name
    subscriptions: topic.subscriptions
  }
}]
```

##### Subscriptions.bicep

```
param servicebusNamespaceName string
param topicName string
param subscriptions array = ['asubscription','anotherone']

resource sub 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2022-10-01-preview' = [for i in subscriptions: {
  name: '${servicebusNamespaceName}/${topicName}/${i}'
  properties: {}
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Essentially I have a set number of topic names (approximately 5) and then for each topic I have N (where N ranges between 1 and 4) subscriptions to assign to a topic, but each subscription has a specific name. I did initially try an object map parameter with a topic string and array of subscriptions but couldn't work out a way to marry the two together. Does the nesting in your answer imply the parent relationship?

Comment: Nesting does imply parent, yes. See my updated answer for the object map example  If you need specific subscription names, I've updated my answer to include how to do that.  Previous versions are pushed to this repo directory. https://github.com/Gordonby/Snippets/tree/master/Bicep/servicebus

Comment: Thanks for all of your efforts! I've marked as accepted answer and will try these out tomorrow 